How to set first button radius in tailwind DaisyUi button group if it has only one button or with dynamic buttons in Angular
I am using tailwind CSS and using dynamic elements to render the buttons in the grouped view, if it has more then one button the design looks fine as first and the last button borders are curved as seen below.

<div class="join">
 <button class="btn join-item bg-black">Button</button>
 <button class="btn join-item bg-black">Button</button>
 <button class="btn join-item bg-black">Button</button>
</div>

Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/enF3BnmYH3
Code ref: https://daisyui.com/components/join/
But when there is one button in the group the left side is not curved.
<div class="join">
 <button class="btn join-item bg-black">Button</button>
</div>


In your components CSS use following code
.join .join-item:last-child:not(:first-child), 
.join *:last-child:not(:first-child) .join-item {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important;
}


I do not get the same issue you raise on the posted tailwind playground or in my local project with daisyui.
<div class="join py-8 px-4">
  <button class="btn join-item">Button</button>
  <button class="btn join-item">Button</button>
  <button class="btn join-item">Button</button>
</div>


Removing 2 button elements.
<div class="join py-8 px-4">
  <button class="btn join-item">Button</button>
</div>


Version
"daisyui": "^4.10.1",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",

However, you may consider removing the css classes join and join-item if it's a single button. You can apply ngClass if you need to apply it conditionally.
